# Tooltip position on left side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code which displays a tool tip on mouse hover. How do I make the tool tip text to be displayed on the next line and on the left side? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XZWhJ/1/)

```html
<div id="demo">
   <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line"> Tooltip 1</p>
   <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line">Tooltip 2</p>
   <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line">Tooltip 3</p>
   <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line">Tooltip 4</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.tooltip {
    display:none;
    font-size:12px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#eee;
}
```

JS

```js
$("#demo img[title]").tooltip();
```

Comment: I find it very confusing, you have not added jquery ui reference in your demo link.

Comment: add jquery-ui.js  and jquery.js to your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are using the jQuery UI Tooltip plugin.

[if you have a look at the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position) you can see that you can specify the tooltip position with something like this:

```
$("#demo p[title]").tooltip({
    track: false,
    position: {my: "left top", at: "left bottom"}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No Javascript required...

Show the elements `title` attribute on the line below

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XZWhJ/7/

### [Your] HTML

```
<div id="demo">
  <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line"> Tooltip 1</p>
  <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line">Tooltip 2</p>
  <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line">Tooltip 3</p>
  <p title="The tooltip text I want this in next line">Tooltip 4</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#demo p[title] {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em; /* leave enough space for the tooltip */
}

#demo p[title]:hover:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1em; /* place it below the parent */
}
```

Comment: I want the tool tip to be displayed and "I want this in next line" line should be displayed in the next line within the tool tip only.

Comment: @Bittu do you mean you want to split the tooltip over multiple lines? http://jsfiddle.net/XZWhJ/10/

Comment: and position it towards left.

Comment: @Bitu You do not control the tooltip position. It shows up wherever the mouse invokes it. If you want to do this then you should be using a different method entirely.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle of that too?

Comment: @Bitu to confirm: does my original answer give you something close or not?

Comment: Yes. But I mentioned two things in my question. One is tool tip in 2 lines and the other is positioning on left side.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/PxHKG/ but split the tool tip to 2 lines